# Traveling Engineering Consultant

Tags: working-visas, digital-nomads

All, I was referred here from travel.stackexchange. MY whole life I have lived in upstate NY. This is not enough for me. I want to spend the majority of my time travelling to other countries and working with new people. As of right now I hold a B.S. in Computer Engineering, M.S. in Electrical Engineering, and am temporarily working as a software engineer. I have heard and done research about software consultants that get to travel to many other countries, and since they are being hired by companies their travel expenses are paid for. I have not seen any similar thing for hardware/ASIC design engineers (area in which I'm passionate). Do these types of jobs exist? I am planning on getting more experience as a digital design engineer before pursuing anything officially.

Also, If these jobs do exists, what would the best way to find a client base. and where would most of these jobs be? I am comfortable spending long periods of time at one location if need be, and I am also fine with traveling for just a week.

If there isn't any need for a Hardware engineering consultant, are there any other jobs that I would be able to use my knowledge base and still be paid to travel. Some people have suggested getting a job where I can remote in consistently so that I could travel whenever I want, but I don't like the idea of paying to travel, to just stay in my hotel room or a cafe doing work.

Also, since I would hypothetically be traveling to many countries for various amounts of time, how would the visa system work. Is it entirely country dependent?

Comment: We seem to share a similar interest.  I would like very much to one day work and live in another country.  I'm so ignorant about how to make this transformation.  How does a US citizen go abroad?  We see many from India, China, and other places coming here in search of a visa (I presume) in exchange for a lower salary.  I was told that I would have to take a cut in pay to go abroad.  I was also told by someone else that this is not true.  How does one begin this journey?  I think it is country dependent.  Upvote for your question and I'll follow you for answers.